# Command takes 10 minutes to run after 2 successful runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command that allows me to edit text channel information like the name, topic, ect.

When running the command, I would run it the same each time: `.channel > React with E, React with N, type name` I would repeat this two or three times, and usually on the third attempt it would wait 10 minutes before actually changing the name and editing the embed, I've asked a friend and both of us are lost on what to do in this situation.

I also don't know if defining the 'editstart' function so I can use 'back' is the best way of doing things, but it was one of the first things I came up with when hit with the dilemma.

Code: (I have remove a lot, but kept all the important bits)

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def channel(self, ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(colour=author.colour)

    ...

    message=await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    try:
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in emojis
        reaction, user=await self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15, check=check)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            information=discord.Embed(colour=author.colour)

            ...

            reactions=[...]
            async def addreact():
                for reaction in reactions:
                    await message.add_reaction(f'{reaction}')
            await addreact()

            async def editstart():
                try:
                    def check(reaction, user):
                        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in reactions
                    reaction, user=await self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)

                    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                        ...

                        try:
                            def check(name):
                                return name.author == ctx.author and name.channel == ctx.channel
                            name=await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)

                            if name.content.lower() == 'back':
                                await name.delete()
                                await message.edit(embed=information)
                                await addreact()
                                await editstart()
                            elif name.content.lower() == 'cancel':
                                embed=discord.Embed(colour=author.colour)

                                ...

                                await name.delete()
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                            else:
                                embed=discord.Embed(colour=author.colour)

                                ...

                                await channel.edit(name=f"{name.content}")
                                await name.delete()
                                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                            await ctx.send(embed=timeouterror, delete_after=3)
                    elif str(reaction.emoji) == ...:
                        ...
                    ...
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    ...
            await editstart()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        ...
```

Comment: The ratelimit for changing channel names is 2 times per 10 minutes per channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord API has many undocumented per-route sub-limits in addition to the global rate limit. Their official reasoning for not documenting the limits is because "they can change at any time. We make no guarantees that rate limits will remain the same" ([source](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1900#issuecomment-674503017)).

Currently, channel name change request as well as many other guild updates (such as channel topic change, channel nsfw toggle, etc.) is limited to twice per 10 minutes.

Your code "stalls" for 10 minutes because under the hood, Discord API returns back to discord.py a 429 Rate Limit response and a retry time, then discord.py internally handles the rate limit and waits out the rate limit then re-runs your command again. If you don't want this behaviour, it's recommended to set a command cooldown and/or add a forced request timeout via `asyncio.wait_for()`.

```
import asyncio

# twice per 600 seconds (10 minutes), per channel
@commands.cooldown(2, 600, commands.BucketType.channel)
@bot.command()
async def changename(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, name):
    try:
        # waits at most 5 seconds, raise exception if takes longer than that
        await asyncio.wait_for(channel.edit(name=name), 5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Failed to change name! Try again later.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Name was changed!")


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"This command is on cooldown! Try again in {error.retry_after:.1f} second(s).")
```